# AngularJS: Trying to use a service, get error "cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I'm trying to use authenticate with a JWT using my api in Laravel, and it works when I just do the authentication in the controller but I'm trying to do this proper and use a service, however I'm getting an error.

The thing is, when I refresh after the error, it redirects to the dashboard (set that up in app.js), which means a user is authenticated.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it giving me this error?:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

...it should be redirecting to the 'dashboard' route. The error is at `.then(function(data)` in the controller.

Here is my service:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('userService', ['$http', '$auth', userService]);

    function userService($http, $auth) {
        var service = {
            userLogin: userLogin
        };

        return service;

        function userLogin(credentials) {
            $auth.login(credentials)
                .then(function() {
                    $http.get('/api/v1/authenticate/user')
                        .success(function(res) {
                            return res;
                        })
                        .error(function(error) {
                            return error;
                        });
            });
        };
    };

})();
```

And here is my controller:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginController', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'userService', LoginController]);

    function LoginController($state, $rootScope, userService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.login = login;
        vm.error;

        function login() {
            var credentials = {
                email: vm.email,
                password: vm.password
            };

            userService.userLogin(credentials)
                .then(function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        var user = JSON.stringify(data.user);

                        localStorage.setItem('user', user);

                        $rootScope.currentUser = data.user;

                        $state.go('dashboard');
                    } else {
                        vm.error = error;
                    }
                });
        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the service, you should return a promise if you want to "then" the method. In that service, userLogin method is returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your service a callback, or use $q.deferred.

```
function userService($auth, $http) {
    return {
        userLogin: function(url, credentials, callback) {
            $auth.login(credentials).then(function(data) {
                $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
                    callback(res);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And in your controller

```
userService("/api/v1/authenticate/user", {password: "pwd", email: "me@me.com"}, function(res) {
    res.status; //200
    res.data; //whatever you got back from the GET request
});
```

To be more precise, you're getting `cannot read property then of undefined` because you're not returning anything to the original invoker. By default javascript will return `undefined` if nothing is returned, so you get `undefined` when you try to synchronously return an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1):

In service you can make use of $q service provided by angular like this

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('userService', ['$http', '$auth', '$q', userService]);

    function userService($http, $auth, $q) {
        var service = {
            userLogin: userLogin
        };

        return service;

        function userLogin(credentials) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $auth.login(credentials)
                .then(function() {
                    $http.get('/api/v1/authenticate/user')
                        .success(function(res) {
                            // return res;
                            deferred.resolve(res);
                        })
                        .error(function(error) {
                            // return error;
                            deferred.reject(error);
                        });
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
    };

})();
```

And in controller you can call the service function as you are currently doing..

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginController', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'userService', LoginController]);

    function LoginController($state, $rootScope, userService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.login = login;
        vm.error;

        function login() {
            var credentials = {
                email: vm.email,
                password: vm.password
            };

            userService.userLogin(credentials)
                .then(function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        var user = JSON.stringify(data.user);

                        localStorage.setItem('user', user);

                        $rootScope.currentUser = data.user;

                        $state.go('dashboard');
                    } else {
                        vm.error = error;
                    }
                });
        }
    }

})();
```

Hope this helps.